# Executing method 1 to N times per second

Tags: java, methods, time, timer

Let's take the following execution example:

```
MyRequest request = new MyRequest(args);
request.execute(params);
```

How can I perform the above `1` to `n` times (i.e. `n=50`) per second?

**Edit**

Furthermore, if we have `i` objects, each of which call `n` requests:

```
for(MyObject obj : objects) {
    // Execute n requests (i.e. in for loop)
}
```

How can I ensure that the execution happens within one second?

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that n requests are executed in 1 Second you would have to know how long 1 execution lasts to run them sequential, otherwise you should use Threads to run them in parralel and start them with a delay to exactly fit 1 Second

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
   MyRequest request = new MyRequest(args);
   Thread th=new Thread(()-> request.execute());
   th.start();
   Thread.sleep(1000/n);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Will this still apply to my edit I just made?

Comment: Do you want the first obj to call n exectue()'s in 1Second and then the next obj n execute()'s in the next Second? If so you would just substitute the Thread.sleep(1000/n); with Thread.sleep(1000/objects.size());
If you want all obj in objects to execute n calls in 1 Second in parallel:
`for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
   for(MyObject obj : objects) {
     Thread th=new Thread(()-> obj.execute());
     th.start();
  }
   Thread.sleep(1000/objects.size());
}`

Comment: You understand that creating and starting a thread isn't coming for free. Starting 50 threads would probably add a significant performance penalty.

Comment: Beware that the `start()` method of the `Thread` class does not guarantee that the thread will actually execute, that is left up to the thread scheduler, so `n` executions are not guaranteed to execute in `n` seconds.

Comment: @AdamMcClenaghan thats true, however the aim is to have `n` executions within one second. Is there a way that this can be guaranteed? As for performance @GhostCat - this is required for a research task where performance penalties aren't a worry :)